# I am trying to replace ' for '' in php, help please

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to replace all ' matched in one string in php but I dont understabnd why it is not working this. I am newer in php.

the instruction is :

```
$val = "Hello I'm newer in PHP.";
$val = str_replace("'", "''", $val);
```

I tried to set backslah before and it is not working too

Could you help me please?

Comment: $val = "Hello I'm newer in PHP."; $val = str_replace(chr(39), chr(34), $val);

Comment: why do you need them replaced?

Comment: sorry i wrote bad here, no no it is fine in my code

Comment: I need to replace them because I want to save it in mysql

Comment: why not just use the mysql_real_escape_string(); function? assuming you haven't upgraded to the new/better mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to make your string "db-safe". You have several options here:

1. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're using the "old-school" mysql drivers (mysql_connect):

   $str = mysql_real_escape_string("I'm newer to PHP");
2. Use `PDO::quote()` if your are using PDO:

   $conn = new PDO(....);
   $str = $conn->quote("I'm newer to PHP");
3. use prepared statements to insert / update tables (see http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Personally I would prefer prepared statements, as it would also speed up your queries if you do multiple inserts/updates, and is the safest way.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your sample. My idea is to build a particular MVC without using Zend. Just to enjoy PHP and buiklding a project. My idea is in the controller when it is a view to show a tbable to buyild the WHERE inside a function I build the WHERE of the data. I use an dictionary to get the values from the form and types from the dictionary. The problem is when I set the value I had to escape it. I think with this idea the best option that you exposed is the first one (exposed for iamde_coder too)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a missing semicolon at the end of your first line, there's nothing wrong with the code you've written:

```
$val = "Hello I'm newer in PHP.";
$val = str_replace("'", "''", $val);
echo $val; // Hello I''m newer in PHP.
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: when I write in database I need to set as Hello I''m newer in PHP to be recognized for mysql